# How to prevent confidential data from being included in WebPack bundles

Tags: webpack, configuration-files, secret-key

I'm worried that, by ommission, modules containing secrets like database passwords or session keys could be included in WebPack or Browserify bundles.

Even if I don't import those modules directly, I could accidentally import them *indirectly* from the client-side entrypoint module.

Is there a way to blacklist such files so that those bundlers will refuse to bundle them? As willing as one might be to follow best practices that could avoid problems like this, it would be nice to have such a safety net.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When importing files via [loaders](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders), you can choose either to blacklist or whitelist directories through the `include` and `exclude` properties.  These can be a RegEx or absolute paths.

### A simple example

The following prevents any JavaScript file from being included in the bundle that exists in the `./secret` directory.

```
 var path = require('path');
        module.exports = {
          // Configuration omitted for brevity
          module :{
            loaders : [
                { 
                  test: /\.js$/, 
                  loader: "script",
                  exclude : path.resolve(__dirname, './secret')  // Exclude secret directory
                },
                { 
                  test: /\.css$/, 
                  loader: "style!css" 
                }
            ]
          }
        };
```

### Complex example applying filters for all loaders

If you wanted to prevent files from the `./secret` directory from being accidentally imported, and only allow files within that contain `src` you could do the following.

```
var path = require('path');
var blackList = [ path.resolve(__dirname, './secret') ];
var whiteList = [ /src/ ]; // Allow only directories containing "src"

var config = { 
...
/// Webpack configuration
};

// Apply whitelisting and blacklisting for all loaders
config.module.loaders.forEach(function(loader)
{
   loader['exclude'] = [...(loader['exclude'] || []), ...blackList];
   loader['include'] = [...(loader['include'] || []), ...whiteList];
});

module.exports = config;
```

The example is a bit complex, but it should give you a good idea how to perform it.  In a nutshell, loop though your loaders and append additional includes/excludes as needed.

#### Bonus: Give type to your secret data

If you do have confidential data existing in your code base, I suggest providing a type to the filename. For example, if your file was named `sqlconnections.js` I would rename it to `sqlconnections.confidential.js`.  Then I would add an **exclude** RegEx pattern of `/\.confidential\.js$/` to my loaders.  This creates a convention that can be reused across your code base.

Comment: Good catch, thanks :) Would you do this yourself though? Just wondering what's common practice.

Comment: I can't say I've seen this in the wild, but most of the examples out there don't really cover your specific question.  Also, most codebases tend to not actually contain confidential data, but rely on other build processes to add it into their production builds.

I've updated my answer to include a suggestion on secret data in general.

Comment: Thought of that. If the bundle build process doesn't have access to any sensitive data, the problem is gone. I know it's not ideal, but I was thinking it wasn't too uncommon for people, especially on smaller teams, to build production bundles on their local machines.

Comment: I can definitely see cases where this could happen.  Especially where people are globing their resources.  Its a good question, hope it gets some up votes :)